# Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE with EXTRA_OUTPUT in internal memory

Tags: android, camera, android-sdcard

When I'm taking a photo from a camera if I'm calling

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/myImage.jpg");
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

`OK button` on camera app is not functioning, simply does nothing (actually won't save it to internal memory I provided I guess and therefore the app itself does nothing).

If I however call

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myImage.jpg");
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

everything is fine and photo is stored on SDCard.

My question is, is there a way to store capture photo in **full-resolution** without SDCard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The native camera app cannot save the image in your app's private internal directories as those are only available to your particular app.

Instead you can create a custom camera activity to save images to your internal directories or you need to use the stock camera app with external storage.

Note: if you plan on creating a custom camera activity make sure you target at least 2.3 and up. Anything below that mark is very difficult to work with.

Comment: Yeah, I targeted 2.2 and up. Custom camera activity seems the only solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you're targeting 2.2 I would try to avoid camera rotation. Rotating the camera in pre 2.3 devices is nearly impossible due to hardware bugs and just old software. (Or just don't allow rotation in pre 2.3 devices)

Answer (score 5):

The Camera activity will not be able to save the file into your activity's private files directory, that's why it fails quietly. You can move the image from the external storage into your files dir in onActivityResult.

Comment: The idea is that external storage is not available (user pulled out SD-Card).

Comment: I think it's reasonable to ask the user to insert an SD card in order to take pictures. Otherwise you risk filling up their (limited) internal memory as well as making it harder to access these pictures.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add permission

```
cameraIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

This is possible using the file provider. Please refer sample

```
  public getOutputUri(@NonNull Context pContext) {
    String photo = photo.jpeg;//your file name
    File photoFile = new File(pContext.getFilesDir(), photo);
    Uri lProviderPath = FileProvider.getUriForFile(pContext,
        pContext.getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile);
    return lProviderPath;
  }



  private void capturePhoto() {
      Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getOutputUri(this));
      cameraIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
      startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);
  }
```

Refer following android document for more details
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider