# ProgressDialog not showing on Galaxy S3 when there is no SD card

Tags: android, progressdialog, sd-card, android-sdcard

Ok I have a weird one here if anyone can answer it.

I have an application which launches the default camera takes a picture and uploads it to a server. The upload process happens in an internal class which extends AsyncTask. Before calling the async task I have a method which shows a progress dialog which is then dismissed in the onPost Execute method of the AsyncTask. 
This all works fine on my own device. The problem arises when I test it on a Samsung Galaxy S3.

I get a null pointer exception on the progressDialog.Show(); which doesn’t crash the application it simply doesn’t show the dialog. But I do get a crash when I try to dismiss the dialog onPostExecute.
I thought it was being caused because the S3’s camera seems to only open in landscape (despite my whole application being locked to portrait in every way Google could tell me is possible) and the orientation change was causing a refresh on the activity causing the reference to progressDialog to be lost.

No amount of changing where the dialog is instantiated (onPreExecute() does work but I still get the same issue), checking if it was null or saving Instance state has fixed this issue. I read in another post that some people were having issues when saving to the SD card. The S3 didn’t have an SD card but the app was trying to write to external storage. I tried doing a check to see if there is an sd card using.

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

Which actually returned true even without an SD card. It wasn’t critical that the image get written to external storage so I tried just getting a cached copy with this.

```
File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, 
            JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, 
            this.getCacheDir()
            );
```

This also made no difference. Why you ask do I care about this SD card issue it couldn’t possibly be affecting the Progress Dialog. Well if I put an SD card into the S3 the problem goes away and the progress dialog appear perfectly. I have no idea why this works but I can’t guarantee that people using the app will have an SD card in their devices so I need to find a proper fix.

Sorry for the essay but I thought it needed a bit of explaining to get a clear understanding.  Any ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

The code below is a stripped down version of what i'm using I tried to include only the relevant material.

```
 @Override  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.compare_layout_activity);

          findViewById(R.id.bCompare).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
          public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
           capturedImage = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(isNetworkAvailable()){
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(capturedImage));
            startActivityForResult(i, REQ_CODE_PHOTO_TAKE);
        }
        else{
            displayAlert("Network Error", "You do not have access to the internet. Please turn on your WiFi.");
            }           
         }      
     });

}


protected File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = 
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, 
                JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, 
                this.getCacheDir()
                );

        capturedImagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();

        return image;
    }

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        showProgressDialog();
        new LongOperation(getApplicationContext()).execute("");

    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

    }               
}


private void showProgressDialog(){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Checking progress");
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.show();

  }

//I wont include the full async task because the code executes fine except for the crash on the show progress Dialog so i'll include the onPostExecute
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.dismiss(); 
    }
```

Almost forgot to include the stack trace although it's not the most helpful information. This occurs on the progressDialog.show();

```
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994): Activity com.activity.CompareActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41ed6318 that was originally added here
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.activity.CompareActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41ed6318 that was originally added here
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:402)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:311)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:558)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at com.activity.CompareActivity.showProgressDialog(CompareActivity.java:324)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at com.activity.CompareActivity.onActivityResult(CompareActivity.java:249)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5368)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2130)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3553)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-27 18:11:33.945: E/WindowManager(21994):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is external storage a necessity? Could you just save to the app's own allotted internal storage?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Using internal storage seems to be the way to go about this but you can not access your applications internal storage from the the default camera activity. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402187/android-action-image-capture-with-extra-output-in-internal-memory). I'll have to try creating a custom camera activity but it's low priority at the moment so it will have to wait.

Comment: @DavidMcEvilly I know that it is a very old question (more than 2yrs) but I am experiencing exactly the same issue here and have no idea about what to do. Do you remember what did you do to solve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about a different pattern, such as:

1. Activity A starts Camera Activity
2. CameraActivity returns control to Activity A
3. Activity A immediately starts Activity B
4. Activity B has no layout/an identical layout
5. Activity B handles the AsyncTask and ProgressDialog.

If the issue is somehow related to the Activity that was alive before and after the Camera Activity, this could potentially solve the issue, by creating a totally new Activity (clean slate) to handle the uploading. What do you think?